# код по алгоритму Иосифа Флавия (последний выживший) выдает неправильные результаты с большими числами

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Попытался написать программу на нахождение последнего в списке числа. Вводится число n (количество человек) и k (каждый k из списка удаляется). С маленькими числами программа работает корректно, но с большими (например 50 и 25) выдает неправильный ответ. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так)
Прикладываю код:

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
m = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
while len(m) > 1:
    del m[(k - 1) % len(m)]
    m = m[(k - 1) % len(m):] + m[:(k - 1) % len(m)]
print(*m)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот вы удалили `(k - 1) % len(m)` элемент

```
del m[(k - 1) % len(m)]
```

а зачем вы дальше формируете новый массив таким образом

```
m = m[(k - 1) % len(m):] + m[:(k - 1) % len(m)]
```

при этом используя новую длину массива

попробуйте так (для теста привел другой код алгоритма)

```
n = 50 #int(input())
k = 25 #int(input())
m = list(range(1, n + 1))
while len(m) > 1:
    x = (k - 1) % len(m)
    del m[x]
    m = m[x:] + m[:x]
print(*m)

def f(n , m):
    return 1 if n == 0 else 1 + (f(n - 1, m) + m - 1) % n

print(f(n, k))
```

Comment: почему? вы в массиве правую и левую части меняете местами

Comment: Вы правы, я ошибся.